# Airflow reset environment variable while running bashoperator

Tags: python, airflow

With one of my airflow task, I have an environment variable issue.

```
[2019-08-19 04:51:04,603] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO -   File "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/versions/3.6.7/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
[2019-08-19 04:51:04,603] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO -     raise KeyError(key) from None
[2019-08-19 04:51:04,603] {{bash_operator.py:127}} INFO - KeyError: 'HOME'
[2019-08-19 04:51:04,639] {{bash_operator.py:131}} INFO - Command exited with return code 1
```

And my task is the following:

```
task_name = BashOperator(
    task_id='task_name',
    bash_command="cd path/to/manage.py && export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 && export LANG=C.UTF-8 "
    f'&& {Variable.get("python_virtualenv_path")}virtual-env-name/bin/python manage.py command_name',
    retries=1,
    pool='LightAndFast',
    dag=dag
)
```

Any ideas of this issue?

Comment: Please post entire stack trace

Comment: Did you try [explicitly setting](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py#L48) environment variables via `BashOperator`?

Answer (score 2):

This is true that airflow resets environment variable, when using `BashOperator`, at least I faced this issue. In documentation of the operator, available at :
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/operators/bash_operator.html,
I found the way to explicitly set the environment for the bash command i.e.

```
bash_task = BashOperator(
        task_id="bash_task",
        bash_command='echo "here is the message: \'$message\'"',
        env={'message': '{{ dag_run.conf["message"] if dag_run else "" }}'},
    )
```

Hence I explicitly set the environment for the Bash command as:

```
env = os.environ.copy(),
```

make sure to `import os`, earlier on in the **dag** file. And it resolved the issue for me.

Comment: I think their docstring for BashOperator is misleading: when `env` is None, "inheriting the current process environment [is] the default behavior." If os.environ is the current process environment, why would `bash_command="echo '{}'".format(os.environ['message'])` work while `bash_command="echo $message"` doesn't?

Comment: do you have the entire code for this? I m trying to explictly set the variable also...

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would place all the environmental variables as a file within -
`/etc/default/`

eg.
`/etc/default/airflow_vars`

airflow_vars would contain your environmental variables, stuff like -

> AIRFLOW_HOME="WHERE YOUR AIRFLOW WAS INSTALLED"
>
> AIRFLOW_CONFIG="LOCATION OF YOUR AIRFLOW.CFG FILE"
>
> PYTHONPATH="PATH WHERE YOUR REGULAR PYTHON SCRIPTS/UTILITIES ARE"

and so on.

If you use system manager (systemd/supervisord) - you would set up a unit file within
/etc/systemd/system
(This is for systemd!)

> [Unit]
> Description=Airflow Workflow daemon
> After=network-online.target cloud-config.service
> Requires=network-online.target
>
> [Service]
> EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/airflow_vars
>
> User=
>
> Group=
>
> Type=simple
>
> WorkingDirectory=
>
> ExecStart= <location of airflow/bin/airflow webserver/scheduler/worker>
>
> Restart=always
>
> RestartSec=5s
>
> [Install]
>
> WantedBy=multi-user.target

Now all your environmental variables are available in your airflow installation.

Another way, is to simply set them up in UI under, `Admin` tab, `Variables` selection

This is the link from Airflow documentation on this-

https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/concepts.html?highlight=environmental%20variables#variables