# Ariflow dag doesn't pick up ENVIRONMENT Variables when it starts to run

Tags: environment-variables, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a DAG that uses Environment variables. the Environment variables are set 
in /etc/default/airflow-scheduler

```
export MY_KEY=1234
```

but when I echo MY_KEY in the DAG it doesn't print anything.

I checked the airflow scheduler variables and verified that MY_KEY existed. the command I used for verifying that was:

```
cat /proc/process_id_of_airflow_scheduler/environ
```

anyone can advise me on how to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Just for clarity, are you actually echoing `MY_KEY` or `KEY` as stated?  The latter doesn't match your export.

Comment: @PirateNinjas, I edited my question.

Comment: Could you give some more information around how you're using it? Is it something defined at trigger time? If so are you using the web-server to trigger it? If you're using the web-server, does it have access the the environment variable?

Comment: I am just printing it in one of tasks in the DAG. it is defined in a /etc/default/airflow-scheduler. I am running a dag from airflow UI. how can I check if web-server has access to it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with setting the environment in `/etc/default/airflow-scheduler`. Is this in the docs somewhere? If you're open to alternative strategies, I would normally have a `.env` file in the project and run `source .env` before starting the scheduler. This will let the scheduler see the environment variable.

Comment: You can give [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57550692/airflow-reset-environment-variable-while-running-bashoperator#comment101595723_57550692) a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. I added the key in the /etc/environment and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Centos/Redhat, the key should rather be added in `/etc/sysconfig/airflow` or `/etc/default/airflow` on Debian/Ubuntu. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47226955/4976878).